# SSL certificates and https for AWS hosted django site

Tags: django, amazon-web-services, ssl, https, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a django site hosted on elastic beanstalk. I have obtained a AWS SSL certificate and this has been associated with the load balancer 443 HTTPS port.

In my config file I have:

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
...
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
]

CSRF_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = False
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
```

With this setup I am able to login to the site but the browser displays 'not secure' in the address bar, and if I prepend 'https://' to the urls I get a page stating the connection is not private.

If I add

```
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = True
CSRF_COOKIE_SECURE = True
```

Then it becomes impossible to login (the login page just reloads) or if I got to a incognito browser I get a 'CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.' message.

Apologies for the long question, I've just tried to include ay detail that may be relevant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had my load balancer listener configured wrong for port 4443. I had the instance port and instance protocol as 443 and https whereas they should be 80 and http

Answer (score 0):

In `settings.py`
Add IP and domain in `ALLOWED_HOSTS` list.
You can put `*`, but it is not recomended. `*` means all host are allowed here.

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['your_ip']
```

Comment: thanks @shafik but that does not address the primary issue, Ive amended the question as I think it may not really relate at all

Comment: does https work correctly? Usually this happen if request is not via HTTPS

Comment: no this doesnt work - you get a connection not private page